# Pine script editor not visible on the chart

Tags: pine-script

I see that the pine script editor is supposed to be at the bottom of the chart, but it looks like I'm missing that entire row.
Does anyone know why that is? And where I can find it? I'm on a free plan for now.

Answer (score 0):

Add one of the open-source scripts to your chart. Then click on *Source code*. It should open the `pine editor`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Vitruvius, thanks for this! I tried it as well, but it didn't work. I'll get a paid plan and see if anything changes. Thanks again, all the best